# Yielding from inside a lambda expression in F#

Tags: .net, f#

I've implemented a standard mutable in-place permutations algorithm in F# (if there's some built-in way of doing something similar, I'd be grateful for the information):

```
let permutations f (alphabet:'a array) =
    let swap i j =
        let aux = alphabet.[i]
        alphabet.[i] <- alphabet.[j]
        alphabet.[j] <- aux
    let rec permutations' n =
        if n = alphabet.Length
        then f alphabet
        else
            for i in n..(alphabet.Length-1) do
                swap n i
                permutations' (n+1)
                swap n i
    permutations' 0
```

Although the function is quite versatile I was wondering if there was some way in F# to implement a wrapper function that would yield me the discovered items as a sequence. Something resembling the following (incorrect) F# method:

```
let permutations_seq (alphabet:'a array) =
    seq {
        permutations (fun arr -> yield arr.Clone()) alphabet
    }
```

In `permutations` I don't want to directly `yield` as I'd like to maintain the function general and I don't want the client to always have to pay the price for array cloning.

How would you do it?

Comment: Why can't `permutations` `yield` the uncloned array? That way, the user can decide what exactly does he want to do.

Comment: Also, how exactly do you imagine this to work? Your `permutations` won't return until all permutations have been created, but `permutations_seq` should return immediately and then yield the permutations when asked. Would it be okay if `permutations` ran on another thread, blocked inside `f` most of the time? And what should happen if enumeration of `permuataions_seq` ends prematurely? Should `f` throw an exception?

Comment: @svick: "Why can't permutations yield the uncloned array? " Well, that was my original idea, tbh. But I felt it would feel weird to return a seq with such a strange behavior.

Comment: btw yielding from within a callback looks like an async pattern. ie async workflow or reactive extensions. However the actual code is not really async so better to go with yield maybe.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "yield" results from the lambda function, then the lambda function itself needs to return a sequence (and so the caller of the lambda function needs to return a sequence too). So, there is no way to get what you want without modifying the `permutations` function (because you cannot yield values from code running in one (nested) scope to a list defined in some other (outer) scope).

However, you can change `permutations` to look something like this:

```
let permutations f (alphabet:'a array) =
    let swap i j =
        let aux = alphabet.[i]
        alphabet.[i] <- alphabet.[j]
        alphabet.[j] <- aux
    let rec permutations' n = seq {
        if n = alphabet.Length
        then yield! f alphabet
        else
            for i in n..(alphabet.Length-1) do
                swap n i
                yield! permutations' (n+1)
                swap n i }
    permutations' 0
```

I wrapped `permutations'` in the `seq { .. }` block and added `yield!` before `f alphabet` (so that all elements produced by the function `f` are passed as results) and I also added `yield!` to the recursive call.

Then you can write:

```
permutations (fun arr -> seq { yield arr |> Array.map id }) [|1;2;3|]
```

The code is using `Array.map id` instead of `Clone` so that you get a type-safe copy of the array rather than an `obj` as returned by the .NET cloning mechanism.

However, I suppose that you do not actually need to yield multiple items from the lambda, so you could change `yield! f alphabet` to just `yield f alphabet` (to return just a single element rather than multiple elements) and write:

```
permutations (fun arr -> arr |> Array.map id) [|1;2;3|]
```

This way, you - at least - get a nice way to abstract away the cloning behavior (and you can choose to clone or not to clone the array easily).

Comment: This is not quite right. You would want ``yield f alphabet`` not ``yield! f alphabet``. The result should be a ``seq<'a array>`` not ``seq<`a>``. I'd fix it but am nervous about editing above my station 5k vs 92k ;)

Comment: Also once you remove the flattening yield! passing in ``f`` seems unnecessary. Rather ``permutations [|1;2;3|] |> Seq.map (fun alphabet -> alphabet |> Array.map id)`` to make sure it is cloned

Answer (score 1):

You have to yield the uncloned array. There is the obvious
strange behaviour in that if you call toList on the sequence
then you get an array of the last value of the array. So
the first thing you have to do is `Seq.map` it with
the clone function. Also I don't think there is a need
to make your function recursive if you are allready
working with mutables.

```
let permutations (alphabet:'a array) =
    let swap i j =
        let aux = alphabet.[i]
        alphabet.[i] <- alphabet.[j]
        alphabet.[j] <- aux
    let rec permutations' n = 
        seq {
                if n = alphabet.Length
                then yield alphabet
                else
                    for i in n..(alphabet.Length-1) do
                        swap n i
                        yield! permutations' (n+1)
                        swap n i
        }
    permutations' 0


let a = [|"a"; "b"; "c"; "d"|]
let p =
    (permutations a)
    |> Seq.map (fun arr -> arr.Clone() )
    |> Seq.toList
```

outputs

```
  val p : obj list =
  [[|"a"; "b"; "c"; "d"|]; [|"a"; "b"; "d"; "c"|]; [|"a"; "c"; "b"; "d"|];
   [|"a"; "c"; "d"; "b"|]; [|"a"; "d"; "c"; "b"|]; [|"a"; "d"; "b"; "c"|];
   [|"b"; "a"; "c"; "d"|]; [|"b"; "a"; "d"; "c"|]; [|"b"; "c"; "a"; "d"|];
   [|"b"; "c"; "d"; "a"|]; [|"b"; "d"; "c"; "a"|]; [|"b"; "d"; "a"; "c"|];
   [|"c"; "b"; "a"; "d"|]; [|"c"; "b"; "d"; "a"|]; [|"c"; "a"; "b"; "d"|];
   [|"c"; "a"; "d"; "b"|]; [|"c"; "d"; "a"; "b"|]; [|"c"; "d"; "b"; "a"|];
   [|"d"; "b"; "c"; "a"|]; [|"d"; "b"; "a"; "c"|]; [|"d"; "c"; "b"; "a"|];
   [|"d"; "c"; "a"; "b"|]; [|"d"; "a"; "c"; "b"|]; [|"d"; "a"; "b"; "c"|]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a call back (`reactive`) approach then use
reactive extensions

https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Reactive/blob/master/src/Observable.fs

and write

```
let permutations (alphabet:'a array) =
    Observable.create (fun subscriber ->
      let swap i j =
          let aux = alphabet.[i]
          alphabet.[i] <- alphabet.[j]
          alphabet.[j] <- aux
      let rec permutations' n = 
          seq {
                  if n = alphabet.Length
                  then subscriber.OnNext(alphabet)
                  else
                      for i in n..(alphabet.Length-1) do
                          swap n i
                          permutations' (n+1)
                          swap n i
          }
      permutations' 0
    )
```

Then you can do

```
permutations [|"a"; "b"; "c"|]
|> Observable.map ( fun arr -> arr.Clone() )
|> Observable.ToEnumerable
|> Seq.ToList
```

However note the symetry with respects to the other answer I posted based
on yield so you don't gain much over yield in this case.